# Vagrant Node Version Not Updating in VM

Tags: npm, vagrant, version

I am currently trying to do this:
https://github.com/workshopper/javascripting#run-the-workshop

When I type javascripting it gives me the error:

EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/home/vagrant/.config/workshopper'

From what I've found the EEXIST errors comes from the node version not being updated.

The terminal on my mac shows:

% node -v
v12.18.3

% npm -v
6.14.6

But the terminal inside my Vagrant VM shows:

% node -v
v8.9.4

% npm -v
5.6.0

I am assuming it is because /usr/local/bin is not in my $PATH but I'm not sure how to update that, or even if that is the problem. Been struggling with this for a while and haven't found anything online that fixes it.

How do I update node and npm inside the VM?

Thanks.

[Edit]

Just in the odd case someone has this problem in the future, here is how I managed to fix it.

Inside of the VM run:

nvm ls

check to make sure the default is the latest version (in my case it should have been v12.18.3). If it is not the latest, then use:
nvm alias default (latest version number)

If you don't restart your VM then it may not update the current version. In that case use:

nvm use (latest version number)

And then you should be good to go.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because the node version on my computer was newer than the node version in vagrant. I updated node in vagrant and it worked.

```
nvm install <version>
nvm use <version>
```